# Hibernate mapping exception - Could not determine type for:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Im trying to configure my entities but hibernate throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.sd.entity.SDUserProductAcess,   at table: SDUser, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(productAccess)]
[PersistEngine] Failed to initialize persistence engine!java.lang.NullPointerException
```

These are my Entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class SDObject
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long sdId;
private String sdType;

public long getSdId()
{
    return sdId;
}

public void setSdId(long sdId)
{
    this.sdId = sdId;
}

public String getSdType()
{
    return sdType;
}

public void setSdType(String sdType)
{
    this.sdType = sdType;
}
}
```

The next one:

```
@Entity
public class SDUser extends SDObject
{

@Column(unique = true)
private String code;
private String password;
private SDUserProductAcess productAccess;

public String getCode()
{
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code)
{
    this.code = code;
}

public String getPassword()
{
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password)
{
    this.password = password;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public SDUserProductAcess getProductAccess()
{
    return productAccess;
}

public void setProductAccess(SDUserProductAcess productAccess)
{
    this.productAccess = productAccess;
}
```

The last one:

```
@Entity
public class SDUserProductAcess extends SDObject
{

private boolean adm;

public boolean isAdm()
{
    return adm;
}

public void setAdm(boolean adm)
{
    this.adm = adm;
}
}
```

Hibernate can't determine the type for column productAccess, located in SDUser entity.
I'm new to Hibernate and I can't figure out what is happening.

Should I provide some kind of ID?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `SDUser` you need to add the association info on the `SDUserAccess`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sdId")
private SDUserProductAcess productAccess;
```