# Hibernate mapping exception:could not determine type for column - again

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am getting a Hibernate mapping exception for a simple JPA annotation. This is dead simple **one-to-one** association. 
Everything is using JPA annotation so no xml configuration.

Here is the exception message:

> Could not determine type for: nz.co.threepoints.ps.domain.Address, at table: Company, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(physicalAddress)]

I know you might get this exception if you mix the field and method annotation, but in my case, I am only using field annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String streetNumber;
    private String streetLine1;
    private String streetLine2;
   // getters and setters
}
```

and the Company type:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Address physicalAdress;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The mapping seems straight forward to me, but for some reason I am getting this type of exception even if I use a different type (like User).

I am using `Hibernate 4.3.8.Final` with `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`.

Here's a snippet of my dependency:

```
<!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.16.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is part of the exception stack:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: nz.co.threepoints.ps.domain.User, at table: Company, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
```

Did they change the rules of the game?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417545/3998458) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the mapping of `Address` class in `Company`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id") //column name in company table
private Address physicalAddress;
```

Comment: It is one-to-one mapping, there is no join table.

Comment: use @OneToOne annotation

Comment: Yes, kind o figured this out by looking at other examples. So simple, thought it doesn't need it.