# Hibernate could not determine type

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm stuck with this error :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.mywebsite.entity.Image, at table: User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(profilePhoto)]
```

I know it have been asked a lot but i'm stuck with this. It have been trying for hours and I can't find anything that work ...

Here are my 2 classes :

```
@Entity
public class Image extends com.mywebsite.entity.Entity{

    //System
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    [...]

}


@Entity
public class User extends com.mywebsite.entity.Entity{

    //System
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    [...]

    //Data
    private Image profilePhoto;    
    [...]

}
```

Can someone help me there ?

Comment: Don't you have an annotation before this line? `private Image profilePhoto;`

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416881/hibernate-mapping-exception-could-not-determine-type-for)

Comment: No i don't there is a "private String password;" before

Comment: can you provide the hbm file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Try this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="profilephoto_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "put_name_here_If_You_HaveAForeignKeyConstraint"))    
private Image profilePhoto;
```

ORIGINAL:

---

From [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property):

> Every non static non transient property (field or method depending on the access type) of an entity is considered persistent, unless you annotate it as `@Transient`.

So Hibernate thinks that field is from the database, and it's trying to find that column in your table. Either that column does not exist and it should, in which case you should have an annotation mapping for it like `@Column`; or it doesn't exist on the database and it shouldn't exist, in which case you should use `@Transient` like the documentation suggests.

Comment: So i added @Column(name="profilephoto_id") as you said and the error change a little : com.mywebsite.entity.Image, at table: User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(profilephoto_id)]. The column name in my table user is "profilephoto_id".

Comment: I didn't had to add "foreignKey" it did work without it. I understant why the joincolumn is needed but not why the manytoone ?

Comment: It's to declare the association between the entities.